# Phonegap app crash on ios - where can I find a log?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I've started build an app using phonegap build.
 In iOS it crashes on some occasions and I can't find a log with the crash reason or any data.
I tried using weinre but there was no trace of the crash.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I used to see the logs on Xcode console. You need to dev provisional to see the logs

Comment: try to build with other version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of remote debugger if you have a Mac and xcode with you. The Remote debugger sits in Safari browser. To enable it follow the below steps:

1. Go to the Settings app on your iOS device and navigate to Safari –> Advanced, and toggle on the Web Inspector switch.
2. Now open your desktop Safari and access Safari –> Preferences menu, select the Advanced tab, and ensure that "Show Develop menu in menu bar" check box is enabled.

Now, run your IOS app on xcode. Once making sure that it was running successfully, go ahead and open your Safari Browser and select Develop in the Menu and you can see that your Iphone name being displayed in it. If you hover over it, you can get access your template for debugging. From this web inspector you can make changes to your Javascript or CSS files. You can get to know all the errors and warnings in the App by accessing different parts of the Inspector.